# When I used selenium and requests in Web Crawler, the browser cannot jump to the new URL

Tags: selenium, url, iframe, python-requests

The script uses Requests to get Cookies, and then Selenium to get the data of a web page, beacause iframe in web page, using chromedriver, but only one page can be obtained each time. The next URL can be entered into the address bar, but it can't jump. What's the reason? The code is as follows：

```
for i in range(1,5):
    get_url="https:example.cn/tp_fp/view?m=fp#service_id="+json_text["list"][i]["service_id"]+"&task_id="+json_text["list"][i]["task_id"]+"&procinst_id="+json_text["list"][i]["procinst_id"]+"&pt=done&act=fp/taskcenter/todo"

    print(get_url)
    self.browser.get(get_url) 
    time.sleep(10)
    self.browser.switch_to.frame("formIframe")
    self.ce_name = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='body_0']/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/span").text  
    self.ce_suspent_time = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='rdsj']").get_attribute('value')  
    self.ce_jijifenzi_time = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='rdjjfzsj']").get_attribute('value') 
    self.ce_fazhanduixiang_time = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='fzsj']").get_attribute('value') 

    print(self.ce_name, self.ce_suspent_time, self.ce_jijifenzi_time, self.ce_fazhanduixiang_time)
    self.browser.switch_to.window(self.browser.window_handles[0])
    self.browser.switch_to.default_content()
```